# Am I doing something wrong with Nhibernate Query Over fetch?

Tags: nhibernate, fetch, eager-loading, queryover

I have this

```
   using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Task tAlias = null;
            CompletedTask cAlias = null;

            List<Task> tasks = session.QueryOver<Task>(() => tAlias)
                .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tAlias.Course.Id), courseIds))
                .Fetch(pt => pt.PersonalTaskReminders).Eager
                .List<Task>().ToList().ConvertToLocalTime(student);


            transaction.Commit();

            return tasks;
        }

    PersonalTaskReminders == Collection
```

So a task can have many personalTaskReminders. I am finding though if I set 2 personalTaskReminders(so PersonalTaskReminders will now have 2 rows in it's collection from the db)

That it returns the same task twice.

So if I had 50 personaltaskReminders for that task. I would get 50 results of the same task. I don't understand why.

If I remove the eager loading. I get the one task back from the database as I expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is obvious, because eager fetch causes join with 2 tables. To get rid of duplicated results you should use DistinctRootEntityTransformer.

By the way, NHibernate offers much nicer syntax for `IN` clause. So your query should look like this:

```
    var tasks = Session.QueryOver<Task>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id).IsIn(courseIds)
            .Fetch(pt => pt.PersonalTaskReminders).Eager
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .List<Task>();
```

Comment: @xelibrion - Maybe obvious for you but I had no clue when I saw the raw sql through nhibernate profiler why it was doing a join. What is the difference from just doing a fetch and Fetch().Eager?

Comment: NHibernate can load objects in two ways - eager loading and lazy loading. Eager loading always causes joins. Lazy loading uses select queries and often lead to select N+1 problem. But you can get benefits from lazy loading by specifying batch size in collection mapping, so it will not cause select N+1 problems

Comment: @xelibrion - So fetch tells it to do lazy loading? I thought that was on by default?

Comment: Fetch().Eager tells to do joins. That's why you've got duplicates.

Comment: @xelibrion - Ok. What if I just did .Fetch() and nothing else would that be equal to lazy loading?

Comment: You cannot do just Fetch(). You can do Fetch().Default, Fetch().Lazy (both are equal to lazy loading, if you are going to use one of them please make sure that you have enabled batchsize for relationship) or Fetch().Eager

Comment: I suppose, Fetch().Default also depends on fetch parameter for relationship in mapping. Ayende wrote post about it http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one

Comment: @ xelibrion  - If I have lazy loading at the configuration level I guess there is no point to using .Default(). When you say batchsize your talking about ado_batchsize(in fluent nhibernate?). Since I also have that set to 10 or 20 on the configuration level.

Comment: adonet_batchsize makes sense only for writes. I was talking about batch-size for relationship. Details are here http://ayende.com/blog/3943/nhibernate-mapping-set

Comment: @ xelibrion - I really don't get what they are saying. So they load right away 30 blog items. They they get all the posts of each blog and loop around it and somehow it changes it from 31 queries to 7 queries?

Comment: Exactly. But it could be reduced to 2 queries if they will increase batch-size

Comment: @ xelibrion - What happens if the things your looking file is not in the 30 they load up? Does it load another 30?

Comment: Yes, NHibernate will send one more query and load posts for next 30 blogs.

Comment: @ xelibrion - Then I have 3 questions how do I set it globally(or should you not set it globally(I am using fluent nhibernate) and what is usually the best batch-size number as you said raising it could have reduced it to 2 queries but I am guess raising it too much is bad too.  The last question is with the lazy loading so if I set my batch size it will only get 30 lazy records at a time when I trigger it to do lazy loading? Or does this happen to the parent one only?

Comment: 1. I set it using conventions. 2. It's value depends on how many posts contains each blog. I'd set batch-size value that will lead to load no more than 100-200 rows per select. 3. No, it will load all posts for a bunch of blogs. Batch-size prevents select N+1 problem when inappropriate usage of lazy loading causes loading posts collection for each blog. Batch-size reduces queries count by grouping blogs in a bunch and loads posts for a bunch of blogs instead of single blog

Comment: @xelibrion - I guess my last question is how do I set it using fluent nhibernate?

Comment: @xelibrion - If I set say the BatchSize(20) and use eagar loading will that only return 20 results back or would I need to set MaxResult? Or does BatchSize only effect when using lazy loading?

Comment: BatchSize works only for lazy loading, but it is not something like MaxResult - it just another way to reduce SELECT's count when using lazy loading. Besides, it does not support paging, so it is not good solution if you have thousands items in PersonalTaskReminders collection

Comment: @xelibrion - can you define paging? Are you talking about like when you got a grid view or something and it has paging?

Comment: 1. No, you can't define paging in lazy loading. 2. No, I'm talking about lazy loading. It doesn't matter, paged or not objects which have not loaded references (these references will be lazy loaded)

Comment: @chobo2 @xelibrion - seeing as this question is now answered, can you either take your comments over to a chat room or ask a new question? Thanks.

Comment: @xelibrion - Hey I going through my site with the profile and I have a lazy load so I set a batch size of 25 but it still says I should set a max result(unbounded result) why does batch size not satisfy this? Also I still don't get what paging means in this case. To me it after x results make a number what will bring up another number of results.

Answer (score 1):

Xelibrion's solution is the right way to fix the problem.

To understand why the results are duplicated when doing `Fetch`, you can compare the generated SQL:

Without `Fetch` the fields in the `SELECT` are just your root entity `Task` fields.

With `Fetch` the fields of `PersonalReminder` entities have been added to the `SELECT`. So if you have two `PersonalReminder` registers for the same `Task` you get two registers in the results, and a `DISTINCT` clause would not remove them (as the real returned registers are different because they contain the `PersonalReminder` fields).

The SQL generated with and without `TransformUsing` is exactly the same, but NH processes the returned registers to remove the duplicates.