# NHIbernate fetch returning multiple parent objects

Tags: nhibernate

Can anyone explain why this query would return 12 companies (it has 12 UserAccessList children)

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Company>()
        .Where(x => x.Id == 1) //x => x.Id.IsIn(ids))
        .Fetch(l => l.UserAccessList).Eager()
        .List<Company>();
```

Comment: See answer to this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221362/am-i-doing-something-wrong-with-nhibernate-query-over-fetch/6224217#6224217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in SQL its going to be something like:

```
select * from 
Companies c left outer join UserAccessLists uac on c.Id == uac.CompanyId
where c.id = id
```

And it is giving duplicates in results. How to fix such issues you can read [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/get-unique-results-from-joined-queries.html).

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
var c = session.QueryOver<Company>()
        .Future();

 session.QueryOver<Company>()
        .Fetch(l => l.UserAccessList).Eager()
        .Future();

var list = c.ToList();
```